# Is it possible to push a commit and not a reference in libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

Is it possible to push a commit and not a reference in libgit2 i.e. basically do the equivalent of `git push {remote} {commit}:{branch}`?

When I try to call `git_remote_upload()` with a refspec like `e9c46cd9071113c95f6b3fb48b74f98056abf7a1:refs/heads/master`, it fails with this error:

> No such reference 'e9c46cd9071113c95f6b3fb48b74f98056abf7a1'

Am I doing something wrong or is this feature simply not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody who uses push has added the feature yet. The push functions expect the refspecs to use references for both sides.